# Getting a SSL Error in OpenVas

Tags: security, openvas

This is the first time i'm using a vulnerability scanner to find vulnerabilities in my system. I have chosen OpenVas as the scanner. But when i execute giving the path of the target to scan, i get an error message as 'SSL Error'.
I selected SSL encryption and trusted Certificate authority is 'cacert.pem'. Can anyone please help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that OpenVas was not able to read or detect your certificate. Make sure you have the right file name and path.

Comment: My folder name (having all the files in localhost server) is 'test'. I gave the correct path.                                              Path - "http://localhost/test/"

Comment: How about your certificate, is it named cacert.pem?

Comment: Yes, it is 'cacert.pem'. When execute,  a window will pop up displaying 'SSL setup'. It says to choose my SSL paranoia. And 3 options will be given. 1.) Display and remember the server certificate, do not care about the CA. 2.)Trust the server certificate if and only if it is valid and certified by CA. 3.) Verify that the server certificate is 'valid' and remember it.       These are the 3 options. I selected first one. And get a SSL error.